# Grails Spring Security Default Configuration: How to define default user and password

Tags: grails, spring-security

In pure spring I can do like this

```
<security:authentication-manager>
<security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">       
    <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
</security:authentication-provider>
<security:authentication-provider>
    <security:user-service>
        <security:user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
    </security:user-service>
```

Is it any way to do the same in Grails with Spring Security plugin?

I can implement my own authentication-provide but in this case I will store credentials hardcoded in class.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using InMemoryUserDetailsManager (in resources.groovy):

```
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority

beans = {
    userDetailsService(InMemoryUserDetailsManager,
            [new User('admin', 'password hash', [new SimpleGrantedAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')])])
}
```

Comment: I was need to change password argument from `'password hash'` to `'{noop}password hash'` to make it work. More info: https://spring.io/blog/2017/11/01/spring-security-5-0-0-rc1-released#password-storage-format

Answer (score 1):

Typically this is done in `BootStrap.groovy`, e.g.

```
import com.foo.Role
import com.foo.User
import com.foo.UserRole

class BootStrap {

   def init = {
      def userRole = Role.findOrSaveByAuthority('ROLE_USER')
      def adminRole = Role.findOrSaveByAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')

      if (!User.findByUsername('admin')) {
         def admin = new User(username: 'admin', password: 'admin').save()

         UserRole.create admin, userRole
         UserRole.create admin, adminRole

         User.withSession { it.flush() }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://gist.github.com/alvarosanchez/81968cb76bcf547e9de1) contains an example where you can leverage `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` and the `BooStrap.groovy` to create users.

Here is what I have in `BootStrap.groovy` (I'm loading the password from environment variables in this case):

```
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.UserDetailsManager
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails

class BootStrap {

    UserDetailsManager userDetailsService

    def init = { servletContext ->

        UserDetails user1 = new User('user1', "${System.getenv("USER1_PWD")}", [new SimpleGrantedAuthority('ROLE_USER')])
        userDetailsService.createUser(user1)

        UserDetails user2 = new User('user2', "${System.getenv("USER2_PWD")}", [new SimpleGrantedAuthority('ROLE_USER')])
        userDetailsService.createUser(user2)

    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

and here is my `resources.groovy`

```
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PlaintextPasswordEncoder

beans = {

    userDetailsService(InMemoryUserDetailsManager,[])
    passwordEncoder(PlaintextPasswordEncoder)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Realization of Bootstrapping "default" User, using our `DomainService`(see below)

`import grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional`

`import org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity`

`import java.util.function.Supplier`

`class DomainService {`

```
@Transactional
<T extends GormEntity> T createIfNotExists(Supplier<T> existingFinder, Supplier<T> newInstance) {
    T model = existingFinder.get()
    if (!model) {
        model = newInstance.get()
        model.save()
    }
    model
}
```

}

`class BootStrap {`

```
def grailsApplication

def domainService

def init = { servletContext ->

    log.info 'BOOTSTRAPPING start'

    createSuperAdminIfNotExist()

    log.info 'BOOTSTRAPPING end'

}

def destroy = {
}

void createSuperAdminIfNotExist() {
    def superAdminProperties = grailsApplication.config.academy.user.super_admin

    domainService.createIfNotExists({ AcademyAdmin.findByEmail(superAdminProperties.email) },
            {
                new AcademyAdmin(
                        createdOn: new Date(),
                        name     : superAdminProperties.name,
                        surname  : superAdminProperties.surname,
                        email    : superAdminProperties.email,
                        password : superAdminProperties.password,
                        passwordConfirm: superAdminProperties.password
                )
            })
}
```

`}`

Answer (score -1):

You can use these custom tags provided by grails spring security.

```
<sec:ifLoggedIn>
<li><a><sec:username /></a></li>
<li><g:link controller="logout">Logout</g:link></li>
</sec:ifLoggedIn>
<sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
<li><g:link controller='controller' action='action'>Login</g:link></li>
<li><g:link controller="controller" action="action">Signup</g:link></li>
</sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
```